# Verify if has only a specified parameter in request - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Is it possible to check in laravel, if only a specific field is filled in a request?

Like this: `if($request->filledOnly('email)){}`

If possible how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `has()` method, and you can call it like this:

```
if($request->has('email'))){

    //do one thing
} else {

    //do another
}
```

---

Edit: 
If you want to check for a situation in which only one input is set, you can do something like this: 
Assuming your other inputs are `name, phone, address`, you can check if any of them are set by calling `hasAny` on your `$request`:

```
if (!$request->hasAny['name', 'phone', 'address'])
{

    //now we know none of them are set
    //check if email is set: 
    if ($request->has('email') 
    { 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
if(count($request->except('email')) === 0)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Validator rules in that.

```
$all = $request->all();
$rules = [
    'email' => 'bail|required|email'
];
```

$validator = Validator::make($all, $rules);